# Problem connecting to MongoDB ReplicaSet using Golang and Robo3T

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-replica-set, availability-zone

I am trying hard to connect to my MongoDB Replica Set but nothing seems to work.

I have deployed Replica set with 3 node, each on a separate AWS Availability Zone but in the same Region.

Below is the code I am using to connect to Replica Set.

```go
    mongoURL := "mongodb://myuser:password@<publicIP>:27017,<publicIP>:27017,<publicIP>:27017/?replicaSet=replica01&authSource=admin"
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURL)
    clientOptions = clientOptions.SetMaxPoolSize(100) //100 is default driver setting
    log.Println("Connection String: " + clientOptions.GetURI())
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
```

I have also created DNS mapping and used that also, but that's also not working.
Below is the connection URL
`mongodb://adminuser:password@rs1.domain.com:27017,rs2.domain.com:27017,rs3.domain.com:27017/?replicaSet=replica01&authSource=admin`

### Robo3T

When I am trying to connect Replica Set with Robo3T using public IP I get the following error

> Cannot connect to replica set "IP-RS"[public-ip:27017].  Set's
> primary is unreachable.
>
> Reason: No member of the set is reachable. Reason: Connect failed

When I use sub-domain name to connect to replica set, I get the following error

> Cannot connect to replica set "SRV Replica"[rs1.domain.com:27017].
> Set's primary is unreachable.
>
> Reason: Failed to initialize MongoWorker. Reason: connect failed

Comment: Your server isn't listening on public IP or your firewall rules prohibit communication.

Comment: I am able to `ssh` to all 3 servers(VM) separately. Also port `21017` is open at all servers.

Comment: Neither of the two things you said helps you with troubleshooting/checking the two things I said.

Comment: I allowed port `27017` at VM level and OS (Ubuntu 20.04) level using `sudo ufw allow 27017/tcp` and activated the firewall at OS. but its still not working. I tried to check using `telnet and nmap` and its showing response.

Comment: If you are a beginner, follow official MongoDB documentation as published. If you are not a beginner, debug your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

The problem was the **hostname**. I used the hostname while configuring the replica set.

Here is my configuration

```json
$ config = {
  _id : "mongo-cluster",
   members : [
       {_id : 0, host : "mongo-1:27017"},
       {_id : 1, host : "mongo-2:27017"},
       {_id : 2, host : "mongo-3:27017"},
   ]
}

$ rs.initiate(config)
```

### Solution

I changed the `hostname` with *`private-ip`*.
Please note that, since my 3 replica nodes resides in the same AWS region but in different availability zones, so I used *`private ip`* to make connection between nodes.

```json
$ config = {
  _id : "replica01",
   members : [
       {_id : 0, host : "private-ip:27017"},
       {_id : 1, host : "private-ip:27017"},
       {_id : 2, host : "private-ip:27017"},
   ]
}

rs0:PRIMARY> rs.reconfig(config)
```

**MongoDB conf setting on all 3 nodes**

```yaml
File: /etc/mongod.conf

    net:
      port: 27017
      bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 172.16.1.x (private-ip)

    security:
      keyFile: /opt/mongo/mongo-keyfile

    replication:
      replSetName: replica01
```

**Hostentry on all the 3 nodes**

```yaml
File: /etc/hosts

    172.16.1.x    mongo-1
    172.16.1.x    mongo-2
    172.16.1.x    mongo-3
```

**Your each machine's name should match with the name defined in  `/etc/hosts` file**

```terminal
$ sudo nano /etc/hostname 
mongo-1
```

**Replica Status**

```json
> rs.status()

{
    "set" : "replica01",
    "date" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:45.971Z"),
    "myState" : 2,
    "term" : NumberLong(8),
    "syncSourceHost" : "172.16.1.x:27017",
    "syncSourceId" : 2,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
    "writeMajorityCount" : 2,
    "votingMembersCount" : 3,
    "writableVotingMembersCount" : 3,
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(8)
        },
        "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:41.356Z"),
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(8)
        },
        "readConcernMajorityWallTime" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:41.356Z"),
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(8)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(8)
        },
        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:41.356Z"),
        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:41.356Z")
    },
    "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1615639331, 1),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "172.16.1.x:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 159132,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(8)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:41Z"),
            "syncSourceHost" : "172.16.1.x:27017",
            "syncSourceId" : 2,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 2,
            "configTerm" : 8,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "172.16.1.x:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 62213,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(8)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(8)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:41Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:41Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:45.616Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:44.778Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1615477956, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2021-03-11T15:52:36Z"),
            "configVersion" : 2,
            "configTerm" : 8
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "172.16.1.x:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 62213,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(8)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(8)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:41Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:41Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:45.095Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-03-13T12:42:45.321Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "172.16.1.x:27017",
            "syncSourceId" : 2,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 2,
            "configTerm" : 8
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"2ujactkx3HytFTyWhh+JkzyQy+8="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6936222258616598531")
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1615639361, 1)
}
```

**Go Connection String**

```golang
mongoURL := "mongodb://username:pass@$172.16.1.x:27017,172.16.1.x:27017,172.16.1.x:27017/mydb?replicaSet=replica01&authSource=admin"
```